# ERROR 001409: Failed to write to the output location when writing output of ESRI ArcGISPro 3 arcpy.gapro.JoinFeatures to memory workspace

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro

When using the `arcpy.ga.JoinFeatures` to write the joined feature to the memory workspace, I get error

> ERROR 001409: Failed to write to the output location when writing
> output.

Example:

```
arcpy.gapro.JoinFeatures('C:/my.gdb/polys',
                          'C:/my.gdb/table'
                           r'memory\temp',
                           'JOIN_ONE_TO_ONE',
                           attribute_relationship='pk fk',
                           keep_all_target_features='KEEP_ALL',
                           )
```

I've tried using `r'in_memory\temp'` and also setting the `arcpy.env.workspace` to `'memory'` and passing the layer name only. All with the same error.

No issue on writing to a file geodatabase.

My gut is that it is an issue with the tools in geoanalyst which support multiprocessing through Spark - but i've not yet tried any other tools in the geoanalyst toolbox.

Unfortunately, due to my organsations convoluted licensing and support arrangements with ESRI, I am unable to raise this issue with ESRI or ask on their forums.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the [Considerations for Geoanalytic Desktop tools help](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/geoanalytics-desktop/considerations-for-geoanalytics-desktop-tools.htm) --

> GeoAnalytics Desktop tools do not support the memory workspace.

Comment: Thanks. Imagine a world where ESRI start providing usefully informative error messages. ...